# how to do paypal sandbox mode testing in magento?

Tags: magento-1.7, paypal-express

I want to test **paypal express** payment gateway by enabling the **sandbox mode**.I have enabled it by setting "yes" in the sandbox mode .I don't understand why the cart **page simply gets refresh** while clicking on paypal button.
I have no idea how to know what is going on .
**How can I know** what error occurs and how to solve it ?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you created a sandbox buyer and seller account? Have you configured Magento with your Paypal sandbox username and api credentials? Have you checked your magento log files for any error reports?

Comment: Thanks @paj. Actually the api credentials were wrong. I have fixed that. Now while giving the email and password for sandbox test , it shows the following....."Currently PayPal accounts in India are only able to send payments. This recipient is not eligible to receive funds". So how can I proceed futher ?

Comment: I think you can create seller accounts base in different geographic locations, for example the US. So perhaps you can test it better with a seller account based in a country where paypal accepts funds.

Comment: Ok let me check with this..